# How to position a div in the absolute center of a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here's how I'm doing it and it does work:

`#myDiv { background: red; width: 100px; height: 100px; margin-top: -50px; margin-left: -50px; position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; }`

`<div id="myDiv"></div>`

But the problem is when I scroll down the page, the div no longer appears in the center because it is positioned 50% off the top relative to the original view port height, not the current one. So I guess I would have to listen for a document scroll event and update the position of the div dynamically. Any idea how to do that?

Basically the effect I'm after is for the div to always be in the center even when the user scrolls.

or maybe there's even a pure css solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `position: fixed;` instead of `position: absolute;`
The positioning (top, left etc) will remain the same, but in relation to the window, and not the document.

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/25WAg/

Comment: Yup.  +1 .  Here is a fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/25WAg/

Comment: Thank you, was about to add one myself but you beat me to it. Added yours to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want `position: fixed;`.

To achieve the div in the center of the screen, you're going to want `left: 50%; margin-left: -50px;`

*Note that the negative margin-left is half of the container's width*

Answer (score 0):

```
#myDiv {
    background: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: auto;
    position: fixed;
}

#container {
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
}
```

Then for your HTML :

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="myDiv">DATA</div>
</div>
```

Tell me if it works.